Land facet analyst- TP- 6 position using ArcMap
I want to do it in ArcMap in Land Facet Corridor - Topographic position index tools- Topographic position, 6 category, but I have this error:
Record Call Stack Sequence - Bottom line is error line.
Create_Sample_6_Class_SlopeClass D:\arcGIS_stuff\consultation\brost_climate_change\code\TPI_Code.bas Line : 1107
Land Facet Corridor Tools v. 1.2.884:  Error Number
-2147217256
Description
ERROR 010429: Error in GRID IO: RMPValidate: Invalid Remap data are entered near record 2  and 3 .. Unable to initialize reclass table
ERROR 010067: Error in executing grid expression.
What to do?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
